# Internal Int32 implementation in C#

Tags: c#, struct, value-type

I'm curious about internal implementation of `Int32` in C#. `Int32` is type of structure. How it is getting inherited from `System.ValueType`?
I had googled it but not able to get satisfactorily answer. Hopefully someone will clear my question.

Comment: [public struct Int32](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252)

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` keyword is specifically designed to indicate inheritance from `ValueType`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, you cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly. Instead, **individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic)** to support the creation of value types.